# Select record from List Box and GoTo That Record in the form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a bound form to a SQL Server table.  On that same form I have a listbox that gets distinct loan numbers from that table.  The listbox has 2 columns, the PK and the loan number.  I used the following code to display the record on the bound form they selected in the listbox so that they can edit it if needed.

This was working great until all of a sudden it stopped working for no reason and I get Error 2105 "You can't go to the specified record."

What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub lst_LocalLoanNumberList_Click()
     DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frm_LocalLoanInfo", acGoTo, Me.lst_LocalLoanNumberList.Column(0) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Something must have changed. Is the dataset filtered?

Comment: No filter, just gets messed up when I delete a record, it can no longer find the record in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub lst_LocalLoanNumberList_Click()
       Dim pk_index As Integer
            pk_index = Me.lst_LocalLoanNumberList.Column(0)
            With Form_frm_LocalLoanInfo.Recordset
            .FindFirst "ID_name =" & pk_index 
            Form_frm_LocalLoanInfo.SetFocus
        
                If .NoMatch Then
                    MsgBox "Not found!"
                End If
            End With
End Sub
```

Change `ID_name` with your ID of the form.

Comment: This works!  The problem was when I would delete a record it would get all screwed up.  Marked as a solution.  Thank you.

Comment: When you delete a record you need to `Requery` your ListBox. Glad to have helped you!

Comment: Yeah I was doing that, Me.lst_LocalLoanNumberList.Requery, Me...Refresh, even Me.Repaint just for kicks, nothing worked.